# Geo-spoofing (a desktop app for Debian)?

Tags: debian, android, desktop, geolocation

I want to spoof my location on my android device without jailbreaking.

I saw this [post](https://www.fonegeek.com/change-location/best-gps-location-spoofer-for-ios.html) about desktop software that can spoof mobile device via usb. Can you please help me find a free alternative that can be installed on a debain laptop?

Comment: Ask you question here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RomeoNinov then ppl will blame me for double posting. Plus it's related to debian specifcally.

Comment: When you post the question in other site you should remove this one